# Tensorflow/Keras LinearRegression Warning Error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to convert this model to a Keras Linear regressor.
Current [code](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/basic_regression):

```
run_config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(save_checkpoints_steps=500)

def build_model():
  model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu,
                       input_shape=(train_data.shape[1],)),
    keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(1)
  ])
  optimizer = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(0.001)
  model.compile(loss='mse',
                optimizer=optimizer,
                metrics=['mae'])
  return model
```

I convert it to:

```
  model = models.Sequential()
  model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear', input_shape=(num_features,)))  
  optimizer = keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=learning_rate)
  model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mse', metrics=['mae'])
  return tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(
      keras_model=model, model_dir=model_dir, config=config)
```

There is an infinite loop showing this:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:It seems that global step (tf.train.get_global_step) has not been increased. Current value (could be stable): 0 vs previous value: 0. You could increase the global step by passing tf.train.get_global_step() to Optimizer.apply_gradients or Optimizer.minimize.
```

My learning rate is set to .001: (Tried with .01 and .1) same results.

Comment: Could you please show how you set `config`?

Comment: run_config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(save_checkpoints_steps=500)

Comment: I can't reproduce the warning. It seems to work fine for TF 1.11

Comment: I'm running into the same issue with Keras and Estimator API. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I found this code which seems to work fine: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/tree/tf-keras-census/census/tf-keras/trainer